# “docker pull redis” gets stuck while downloading

Tags: docker, redis

When I invoke "docker pull redis" , I get:

```
    Using default tag: latest
    latest: Pulling from library/redis
    000eee12ec04: Already exists
    5cc53381c195: Already exists
    48bb7bcb5fbf: Already exists
    ef8a890bb1c2: Already exists
    32ada9c6fb0d: Already exists
    76e034b0f296: Waiting
```

Client:

```
 Version:           19.03.1

 API version:       1.40

 Go version:        go1.12.7

 Git commit:        74b1e89e8a

 Built:             Wed Jul 31 15:18:18 2019

 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64

 Experimental:      false
```

Server: Docker Engine - Community

```
 Engine:

  Version:          19.03.5

  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)

  Go version:       go1.12.12

  Git commit:       633a0ea838

  Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:28:45 2019

  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64

  Experimental:     false

 containerd:

  Version:          v1.2.10

  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339

 runc:

  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev

  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657

 docker-init:

  Version:          0.18.0

  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Try run ```docker system prune -f``` and retry download

Comment: @ozlevka Thank you for your input. I've tried it but it looks still the same.                                  $ docker system prune -f
Total reclaimed space: 0B

$ docker pull redis
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/redis
000eee12ec04: Already exists
5cc53381c195: Already exists                                                                              
48bb7bcb5fbf: Already exists
ef8a890bb1c2: Already exists
32ada9c6fb0d: Already exists
76e034b0f296: Waiting

Comment: seems like you are using window, did you enable linux container in docker setting?

Comment: I'm running docker on Windows 10 home edition by installing docker tools.

Comment: enable linxu container and then try